# how to make two copies of a file such that if one copy is changed the other changes too

Tags: windows

I'm using windows 10 and I want to set things up such that I have 2 copies of a file(this is because the actual file is like way too deep so I want to make a copy on the desktop so that if I change the desktop copy it will change the actual one

Comment: Create a shortcut? Right-click the file, select Send To and choose Desktop (create shortcut)

Comment: doesnt seem to work for me